# Issue with formatting the dataset

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Having scraped this data from XML and storing it to a Pandas DataFrame, I wanted to ask if, and how, to format the data according to requirements.

[image: Dataset Image (Updated)]

**Problem 1:** Basically every three rows need to be combined by removing the NaNs, to represent one row.
For example, the correct way to represent this data would be:

```
  qid, qualid, val

0 2065887850, 227, (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
1 2021905255,  30, (49214,.....,...,....)
```

**Problem 2:**

In some places, val variable is actually missing (every third row in original data) and I need to place a NaN for that. The desired output in this case would be. Ideally, I need a solution which solves both problems.

```
  qid, qualid, val

0 2065887850, 227, (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
1 2121905255,  23, (49214,.....,...,....) 
2 2834347850,  17, NaN
3 2121905255, 930, (14124,.....,...,....) 
4 2465212110, 227, (2,2,1,4,6,7,0,0,0,0)
5 2921905225, 130, NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try of converting dataframe to string type and groupby 3 rows and add the rows,

```
      col_1   col_2     col_3
0   29021214    NaN     NaN
1   NaN         227     NaN
2   NaN         NaN     0,0,0,0
4   20218343    NaN     NaN
5   NaN         30      NaN
7   324234      NaN     NaN
8   NaN         532     NaN
9   NaN         NaN     NaN


temp = df.col_1.notnull().cumsum()
df = df.replace(np.nan,'').astype(str)
df.groupby(temp).sum().replace('',np.nan)
```

Out:

```
    col_1       col_2   col_3
col_1           
1   29021214    227    0,0,0,0
2   20218343    30     NaN
3   324234      532.0   NaN
```

Comment: I don't want to add the rows. That would destroy the purpose of the dataset. Each id is unique and unique features associated to it.

Comment: seems your data is representing the one record with the data of  '3 rows', with this logic it wont change the record information, can you show the exceptional case, i will modify it @AbhinavRalhan